# yet another undefined method `model_name' for Project:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I am new to Rails and what I am trying to do is creating a simple client for Youtube. I am using Youtube_it gem to retrieve all the videos in one of my playlists and I am using the code:

controller:

```
class PlaylistsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    client = session[:client]
    @playlist = client.playlist(params[:id])
    @playlist.extend(BasePlaylist)
  end

end
```

module to extend for Youtube_it/Playlist.class:

```
module BasePlaylist
  extend ActiveModel::Naming
  include ActiveModel::Conversion

  def model_name
    'Playlist'
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

playlists/show.html.erb:

```
<h1><%= @playlist.title %></h1>

<%= render 'form' %>
```

playlists/_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@playlist) do |f| %>

    <% @playlist.videos.each do |video| %>
        <div class="field">
          <%= f.check_box_tag video.title %>
          <%= f.label video.title %>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

What I am getting is:

```
undefined method `model_name' for YouTubeIt::Model::Playlist:Class
```

What I did above is trying to "wrap" the Playlist object but it doesn't look to work. Any idea?

Comment: Where and how does the error occur?

Answer (score 0):

While you have defined a module that adds the methods that you want, none of the code in your question shows how that module is added to the Playlist class. I'm not familiar with the YouTubeIt gem so I can't say for sure how you'd do that, but if for example you wanted to add that module to the built-in string class you'd do so like this:

```
class String
    include BasePlaylist
end
```

Comment: I have this in the code: @playlist.extend(BasePlaylist) that does something similar